# Having trouble with caption spacing in a minipage

Tags: spacing, captions, minipage

I have a minipage with 2 figures side by side, but there is no white space between the captions of the respective figures. How can I fix this? Here is what I have:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{a.png}
        \caption{An artificial neuron...}
        \label{figure: a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{n.jpg}
        \caption{This a schematic of...}
        \label{figure: n}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please provide a complete code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. This is necessary because no one knows which document class you are using nor which packages you are using.

Comment: You need to make the minipages narrower, and the figures wider.  `{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}` is a good width for a minipage.  Remeber that inside a minipage, \textwidth is the width of the minpage itself, so effectively 0.25\textwidth for the page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo that worked, thanks!

Comment: @marmot thank you, will do next time